# Sorting NSFetchedResultsController on a instance variable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to show restaurants in a table view. I had restaurants location saved in database and user location saved in a variable. 
Now my problem is how i can show the list of restaurants that is closer to the user location. I can calculate distance run time but how i can show restaurant that is near to user location on top of the list.